# PuTTY plink sending control+C

Tags: unix, putty, plink

I am using Putty plink command line utility to run a few scripts on my UNIX server. I use the -m option as:

```
plink -ssh -pw xxx myserver –m file.txt
```

The file file.txt contains a list of commands that are to be executed and is generated dynamically using some application program. Some of the commands in file.txt can run for hours, which will make the user wait for a long time. Moreover, I am interested in execution of the first line of each of the scripts.

So I want to make sure that a control+c command is sent just after the script is run so that complete script is not run. So instead of using the following in my file.txt:

```
script1
script2
script3
```

I want to use:

```
script1
control+C command
script2
control+C command
script3
control+C command
```

Can anyone help me in writing this control+c in my file.txt?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If it's possible, i'd much prefer to modify the scripts to accept an argument that tells it to quit early.  That's the most reliable way to ensure that you don't interrupt the script too early.  Seems to me that automatically sending an interrupt signal right after issuing the command could potentially cancel the script before the first line even runs.

Comment: Yup I get it, but we are not allowed to modify the scripts or create any new scripts on thr UNIX machine.

Comment: Then it looks like you're going to need to find some kind of automation tool.  Plink wasn't made for scripting interactive sessions (which is where Ctrl+C works).

Comment: I couldn't figure it out and I have created dummy scripts for each of my scripts using the first lines.