# plink.exe use Control-C inside ssh session

Tags: linux, ssh

i am using Putty's plink.exe inside ConEmu to connect to Linux servers over ssh from my Windows desktop.

Works nicely, except for one thing.
Hitting Control-C, which normally sends a "break" inside the Shell session, to a process or whatever, in my case closes plink.exe and drops me back to the Windows cmd.

Any idea how to avoid that ?

Comment: Here read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818414/putty-plink-sending-controlc

Comment: any luck with this? @Steffen Circle